# Integrating django-filer into djangocms-text-ckeditor

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-cms, django-filer

I need a way to use **upload** and **browse** abilities of django-filer in the djangocms-text-ckeditor, for example to upload images in the articles of my site, as I'm typing them in the ckeditor.

Are there any settings that help me with that? Or should I write a compatible browser myself?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that [cmsplugin-filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/cmsplugin-filer) provides what you are looking for. Take a look at the screenshot. From within the ckeditor modal, I can browse django-filer files and integrate them. Is that what you were looking for?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: But now filer have small bug with auto crop/scale image in content (THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS)